# An elementary question about $\varepsilon$.

Tags: real-analysis

Is saying that $x\leq\varepsilon$ $\forall\varepsilon>0$ equivalent to saying $x<0$? Why? Could anyone prove it or at least guide me to prove it?

Comment: Certainly $0\leq \varepsilon$ for $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: It is equivalent to saying $x\le 0$.

Comment: @TooOld Could you prove it please?

Comment: @Charlie: Certainly, see below.

Comment: I thought it means $x=-\infty$ as x is less than any (negative) number.

Comment: In non-standard analysis $x$ could also be greater than $0$ but infinitely small.

Comment: @canaaerus What do you mean with non standard analysis? How would you justify the proof below from a non-standard analysis viewpoint?

Comment: @Charlie: $ε$ is only a standard real-number, so you can't set $ε = x/2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Claim:** $x\le \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ if and only if $x\le 0$.

*Proof:* "$\Rightarrow$": Suppose $x\le \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$. Assume $x>0$. Then set $\epsilon=x/2>0$, therefore $x\le \epsilon=x/2$. Since $x>0$, that implies $1\le 1/2$. Contradiction. So $x\le 0$.

"$\Leftarrow$": Let $x\le 0$. Suppose $\epsilon>0$. Then $x\le 0<\epsilon$. $\square$

Comment: If I assume $x\ge0$ in the $\implies$ part, it follows a contradiction and we can deduce that $x<0$. Am I right?

Comment: @Charlie: No. You cannot conclude by contradiction: the implication $x\le x/2\Rightarrow 1\le 1/2$ is by dividing by $x$. Therefore $x$ **must not be $0$**.

Comment: How could we prove the case $x<0$?

Comment: @Charlie: Ok, I don't really know where your misunderstanding is, so let me explain this for you again. Suppose you go out into wide world and there you meet a real number $x$. All you know about that $x$ is that is not greater than any positive number. What can you conclude? Is $x$ necessarily negative ($x<0$)? No, because the number $0$ is also not greater than any positive number. So all we can say is that $x\le 0$. All negative numbers meet the criterium of not being greater than any positive number, but $0$ **does also**. That is the point.

Comment: Thank you. Everything is clear now.

Comment: @Charlie You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

What if $x = 0$?

But certainly it rules out any $x > 0$, since then $x/2$ (say) would also be greater than $0$, but $x$ would not be less than or equal to it.